# Синонимизировать метки на тему [фронтенд]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

- [фронтенд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4) (49 вопросов) нет описания
- [frontend](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) (1035 вопросов) описание есть

С меткой [frontend](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend) гораздо больше вопросов и у неё есть описание, но [фронтенд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4) - на русском, поэтому не очень понятно, какую делать основной.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Синонимизировано в пользу [frontend](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend)

```
updating post history, 52 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 49 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 40 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'фронтенд': [фронтенд] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 1075
tag remapping of [frontend] and [фронтенд] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
6 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```